# Proving $(1-e^{4})(1-e^x) - (1-e)(1-e^{4x})> 0$ for all $0<x<1$.

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

I need help proving $(1-e^{4})(1-e^x) - (1-e)(1-e^{4x})> 0$ for all $0<x<1$.

This question arrived from solving another question. I wanted to prove that a solution of an ODE was greater than $0$ in $(0,1)$, so I computed the solution and then worked out the desired inequality, getting the inequality of this question. The problem is that I cannot proceed further. I would provide more context or my tries, but I don't have any, because I am stuck.

I think that this inequality has some symmetry. That could be helpful.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $0 < x < 1$ is
$$ 
\frac{e^{4x}-1}{e^x-1} = 1 + e^x + e^{2x}+e^{3x} < 1+e+e^2+e^3 = \frac{e^{4}-1}{e-1}
$$
and that is equivalent to your inequality.

**A generalization:**

> For real numbers $0 < a < b$ and $0 < c < d$ is
> $$
>  (e^{ad}-1)(e^{bc}-1) < (e^{ac}-1)(e^{bd}-1) \, .
> $$

*Proof:* With the substitution $a=e^u$, $b=e^v$, $c=e^s$, $d=e^t$ and the function
$$
 f(x) = \log(e^{e^x}-1)
$$
the claim is equivalent to
$$
 f(u+t)+f(v+s) < f(u+s) +f(v+t)
$$
for $u < v$ and $s < t$, and that is true because $f$ is strictly convex on $\Bbb R$.